# How to create a React class for even and odd numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, class

**I have a code that displays the news of the day. https://ibb.co/QMLY2Kx I have 10 classes named "**block**". Inside the "**block**" class there are two classes named "**blockText**". I need to get two different class names and not the same, I want to get this result "**blockText1**" and "**blockText2**". How to do it? **

```
import React from 'react';
import newsStyle from './News_module.css';

export class News extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const resultsRender = [];


        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.news.length; i += 2) {
            resultsRender.push(
                <div class="block">
                    {
                        this.props.news.slice(i, i + 2).map((news, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div class="blockText" key={index}>
                                    <p class="text">{news.title}</p>
                                    {console.log(this.props.news.length)}
                                </div>
                            );
                        }

                        )
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="headlineSecond">
                    <div className="Second">
                        {resultsRender}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you consider just using CSS for that? `nth-child(odd), nth-child(even)`, this sort of things?

Comment: A good option, I will definitely take this into account in future practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ternary operator for this . Here is an example where i chose the value of class based on the value of index and deciding upon whether it is even or odd

```
<div class={ index%2 ===0 ? "blockText1": "blockText2" } key={index}>

    .....  rest of code 

</div>
```